# Check if model is valid without ModelState.IsValid

Tags: entity-framework

The viewmodel is being passed to my submit action so I cant use: ModelState.IsValid , my form is a property of the view model (Model.Form)

Is there a way/function for me to tell if an entity object is valid according to the attribute parameters in the EF class manually? Or do I have to try and add it and wait for an error?

Comment: Yes already have client side, but need server-side c# validation too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `Validator` class:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

var user = new User { Name = "Sam", Surname = "Smith"};

var errors = new List<ValidationResult>();
if(!Validator.TryValidateObject(user, new ValidationContext(user), errors, true))
{
    //now errors are not empty
}
else  
{
    context.Users.Add(user);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```